# Where can I download the Informix ADO.NET Provider?

Tags: .net, ado.net, informix

We have decided to add Informix support to our application. I wrongly assumed there would be an Informix package on NuGet then I wrongly assumed that IBM would have a download link for the software on their website. But alas no. After an hour of failing to find out where the download link was I had to give up. They have some byzantine process of getting the actual software. Sooo, does anyone know where or how I can obtain the Windows 64 bit ADO.NET provider for Informix? A link would be great but I'd settle for the instructions to get through the IBM website/maze.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016673 Sounds like Google knows it better than IBM web site itself.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not available in NuGet (at least not yet).
You will need to download CSDK (the .NET provider in included inside) from either your Passport Advantage customer page or directly from FixCentral:

[CSDK_4.10.FC11_WIN-x86_64_Fixpack](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?product=ibm%2FInformation%20Management%2FInformix%20Client%20Software%20Development%20Kit&fixids=CSDK_4.10.FC11_WIN-x86_64_Fixpack&source=dbluesearch&function=fixId&parent=ibm/Information%20Management)

Comment: "No applicable IBM support agreement found for one or more of the products you selected."

Really??? I need a support agreement to download an access engine???

Comment: I didn't work for me. I just started the step by step, log-in with new IBM account and it ask for a support contract. Is the Informix ADO.Net Provider free? Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not free. You can only download CSDK from the IBM website with a support contract.

But, you should be able to download the whole server media (and then just choose CSDK during the installation) from the following page:

https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/informix-developer-edition

Pick "Informix Enterprise Time-Limited Edition for Windows 64".

Comment: This is so frustrating. We are facing a huge memory leak in the IBM Informix Driver and we can't even download a fix.

Comment: You can download the latest version of the server (which includes CSDK and the Informix .NET provider) from the link I posted before. If you think there is a memory leak in any of the drivers, I suggest to open a support case.